# How can I easily manage discounts for specific products?

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart. I installed the [Commerce sale price](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_saleprice) module to manage discounts for specific products. It's a great module, but it creates another price to link to products. When I use the filter price, it only filters either regular price or sale price, but never both together.

I know I can create discounts with rules, but I would like to find something simple that can be easily set up when the customer creates a product.

How would you fix this issue?

Comment: If the goal is: "the site administrator can create simple discounts for products".
You can add another field like "discount percentage" . By default would be set as 100 % (or 0% of discount).
Then, with rules, you check if this fields have another value than 100, and recalculates the price.